# How to add superuser account in google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We need a backup superuser account.  Docs say how to add an organizational admin, but that has less permissions and I am already running into permission issues.  How to add a super user account?  I have been on with google support for 3 hours and they have their heads...well..somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you can achieve your goal by granting Super Admin role to at least one extra account. This role is [pre-built](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/2405986?hl=en) and keep in mind that:

> After you assign the Super Admin role to a user, it can take up to 24
>   hours for the calendar privileges to be available.

If you use G Suite you can follow this [guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172176?hl=en&ref_topic=4514291) to grant a Super Admin role.

In addition, have a look at the [Creating and Managing Organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization):

> Each G Suite or Cloud Identity account is associated with exactly one
>   Organization. An Organization is associated with exactly one domain,
>   which is set when the Organization resource is created.
>
> When the Organization resource is created, we communicate its
>   availability to the G Suite or Cloud Identity super admins. **These
>   super admin accounts should be used carefully because they have a lot
>   of control over your organization and all the resources underneath it.
>   For this reason, we do not recommend using G Suite or Cloud Identity
>   super admin accounts for the day-to-day management of your
>   organization.** For more information about using G Suite or Cloud
>   Identity super admin accounts in Google Cloud, see [Super Administrator Account Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/super-admin-best-practices).

**EDIT** Please update your question with details about your permission issues with Organizational admin, but check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) first:

> **The Organization admin, once assigned, can assign IAM roles to other  users**. The responsibilities of the Organization admin role are:
>
> - Defining IAM policies
> - Determining the structure of the Resource Hierarchy
> - **Delegating responsibility over critical components such as Networking, Billing, Resource Hierarchy through IAM roles**
>
> Following the principle of least privilege, this role does not include
>   the permission to perform other actions, such as creating folders.

Check [Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs) documentation and [IAM best practice guides](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/iam-best-practice-guides-available-now) to find more details.